# Return value is always same in useEffect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, use-effect

I have tested my backend API with **postman** and it works fine as it should be. But when I send a request from react js it always return 0. My expected **return value should be 1** as this row already exist in the table. I am pretty sure my backend code is alright and backend code just works fine from postman. What is the wrong in my React js code? Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Frontend React js code is below:

```
const [like, setLike] = useState(0)
useEffect(() => {
        const userObject = {
            from_user_id,
            to_user_id
        }
        likeDisplayService.unlikeDisplay(userObject)
        .then(res => {
            console.log("This is like return value "+ res.value);
            setLike(res.value)
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(("Error: couldn't get like info"))
        })
    }, [])
```

Backend Node js code is bellow:

```
const likesDisplayRouter = require('express').Router()
const db = require('../utils/db')

likesDisplayRouter.get('/', (req, resp) => {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM likes WHERE from_user_id = $1 AND to_user_id = $2',
    [req.body.from_user_id, req.body.to_user_id], (err, res) => {
        if (res && res.rows[0])
            resp.status(200).send({ value: 1 })
        else if (res)
            resp.status(200).send({ value: 0 })
        else
            resp.status(400).send({ value: "Query execution failed"});
    }
    )
})

module.exports = likesDisplayRouter
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `from_user_id` or `to_user_id` have an invalid value, you could do something like:

```html
const [like, setLike] = useState(0)
useEffect(() => {
        //Check if has a valid value
        if (!from_user_id || !to_user_id) return

        const userObject = {
            from_user_id,
            to_user_id
        }
        likeDisplayService.unlikeDisplay(userObject)
        .then(res => {
            console.log("This is like return value "+ res.value);
            setLike(res.value)
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(("Error: couldn't get like info"))
        })

      //On changes in this variables call it again
    }, [from_user_id, to_user_id])
```